# Putting label text over input field

Tags: html, css

I have the following login form:

```
div.field {
    position: relative;
}
label {
   font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 3px;
}​

<div class="username field">
    <label for="username">Enter email</label><br />
    <input type="text" class="field" name="email" id="id_email">
</div>
<div class="password field">
    <label for="password">Enter password</label><br />
    <input type="password" class="field" name="password" id="id_password">
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5yBz5/

Currently, if a user clicks anywhere where the label text is, nothing will happen (i.e., because the user is clicking on the label text instead of the text input). I want the label text to be in the text input, however, when a user clicks on the text input field, it should ignore the label text.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you trying to make a placeholder? If so, use the `placeholder` attribute (and a [polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to make sure it works in older browsers)

Comment: Yes, I know about that (see my previous question). I'm trying to do this via a label.

Comment: never seen something like that... what are you trying to do?

Comment: Honestly, this is just a test I'm trying out. I'm not putting it in production, just seeing how to do it. It's more for learning than anything else.

Comment: By using a pure CSS, you can't do it! Use a `placeholder` or some JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You should check out the html5 [placeholder](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute instead. It's the recommended way of doing this.

Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="placeholder text"></input>
```

Comment: Have checked it out. This is a different question than that.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "almost all browsers support it". Hundreds of millions of people use browsers that do not support placeholder.

Comment: OK sorry, just looks like the obvious solution in this case.

Comment: If the question is: "How to make a placeholder inside an input text", this is the right answer.

Comment: piers: Ok sorry, maybe wasn't really true. However all newest versions of all major browsers support.

Comment: And yes, this solution is not cross-browser. `placeholder` is supported only to the latest browser versions.

Comment: There are numerous polyfills that will allow the `placeholder` attribute to work cross-browser. Here's [one that I wrote](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) (it doesn't need jQuery, and it works in IE6).

Answer (score 1):

Add `onclick="this.innerHTML=''"` to the `label` elements. This is far from a perfect solution, but a solution that has optimal usability would have a different approach (label element before the input element), and the issue would not arise.

Answer (score 1):

Method 2:

Use jQuery (optional) to capture click the event on the label, then focus the input element:

```
​$("label").on("click",function(){
    $(this).parent().children("input").focus();
});​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SsZTh/

Answer (score 1):

Using a label for placeholder text is simply not a good idea, as it provides a horrible user experience for someone trying to fill out your form.

That aside here are a couple of things to make note of:

- close your `input` tags
- The for attribute of the `<label>` tag should be equal to the `id` attribute of the related element to bind them together.

If you want to provide place holder text perform the text replacement with javascript. For example:

```
<div>
    <label for="email">Enter email</label>
    <input type="text" class="defaultText" name="email" id="email" title="Enter email" />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="password">Enter password</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" id="password" />
</div>
```

Note, the use of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $(".defaultText").focus(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title) {
            $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
        }
    });

    $(".defaultText").blur(); 
})();
```

example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yBz5/4/

Answer (score 1):

Set your labels' z-index to -1 and make your input fields transparent.  That way the labels is rendered "behind" the input fields so that when you click on it, the input field receives the event instead of the label.

```
div.field {
    position: relative;
}
label {
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index:-1;
}
input {
    background: transparent;
}
```